# Route is not defined when using laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

i have created laravel package,and have one view test.blade.php showing basic form ,but inside that form when ,try to use route('contact') ,it shows me an error message

> Route [contact] not defined.

my route file web.php in package folder

```
<?php
// matrixhive\testpackage\src\routes\web.php
Route::get('contact', function(){
    return view('testpackage::test');
});

Route::post('contact', function(){
    echo "thanks for submission of form";
});

?>
```

my view file in side package

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
    <body>

      <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 90px;">
        @if(session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif

      <h3>Contact Us</h3>

      <form action="{{route('contact')}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Your name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleFormControlInput" placeholder="John Doe">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Enter Your Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control"name="message" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am learning laravel package development from [here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/publish-laravel-packagist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set name for the route with **name()** method like

```
Route::post('contact', function(){ echo "thanks for submission of form"; })->name('contact');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

*pass name to call route directly*

```
<?php

Route::get('contact', function(){
    return view('testpackage::test');
})->name('contact');

Route::post('contact', function(){ 
    echo "thanks for submission of form";
})->name('contact');

?>
```

Comment: happy coding :) @Jatin parmar